# Mongodb: mongorestore "assertion 13106" for basic example

Tags: mongodb

I tried to run backup/restore example from chapter 7 of 'The Little MongoDB Book'

```
mongodump --db learn --out backup
```

and

```
mongorestore --collection unicorns backup/learn/unicorns.bson
```

*mongodump* excecuted fine, but when I trying to use *mongorestore* I got this error:

```
$ mongorestore --collection unicorns backup/learn/unicorns.bson
connected to: 127.0.0.1
assertion: 13106 nextSafe(): { $err: "Invalid ns [.unicorns]", code: 16256 }
```

How can I fix this? Win7

```
$ mongod --version
db version v2.6.6
2015-01-26T23:29:09.224+1100 git version: 608e8bc319627693b04cc7da29ecc300a5f45a1f

$ mongorestore --version
 version 2.6.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mongorestore is missing db option.  Try

```
.\mongorestore.exe  -db learn --collection unicorns backup/learn/unicorns.bson
```

Comment: unbelievably worked for me too. so what if I want to restore all collections from all databases? can you help me with this case?